# Dropdown Value to ActionLink

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to get the drop down list selected value to use it within the same PartialView :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ModelType, new SelectList(Model.infoModel, "idModele", "nomModel"), new { id = "ModelType" })
```

I need the value of ModelType to use it into instead of 2:

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Order New", "View", new { id = 2 }, new { @class = "viewDialog" })
```

I tried but it didn't work I prefere the to have a way to change the 2 by the dropdown value :

```
 <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="badd" id="badd">
```

at the end of my file I add :

```
 <script>
  $('#badd').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location.replace =
      '<%=Url.Action("Order New","View", "Home")%>' + '?id=' + $('#ModelType').val();
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Order New", "View","Home",null, new { @id = "viewLink" })
```

And listen to the click even on this link, and read the selected value of your dropdown, construct the url use that to load your partial view/navigate to that

```
$(function(){

  $(document).on("click","#viewLink",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     var newUrl="@Url.Action("View","Home")?id="+$("#ModelType").val();
     // you can do whatever you want with the new url 
     //  window.location.href=newUrl;
  });

});
```